# Phantom not working as expected in cases environment

Tags: cases, phantom

In the image below you can see the phantom not taking up as much width as it's expected in the cases environment:

[image]

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M+A+T & =12\\
\phantom{M+}A+T & =10
\end{align*}

\[
\begin{cases}
M+A+T & =12\\
\phantom{M+}A+T & =10
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

My questions are: why doesn't the phantom in the cases environment take up as much space as it does in the align* environment? How can I fix it?

I only have a temporary solution now, which is manually adding some \hspace.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thanks for providing a minimal working example. Try adding a pair of braces `{}` after the `+` as a quick fix, as in `\phantom{M+{}}A+T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically it does; it's the alignment difference between `align` and `cases` that's tripping you up. `align` has a RIGHT-LEFT alignment for elements around `&`, while `cases` has a LEFT-LEFT alignment. As such, the spacing shows (more) clearly in `cases` than `align`.

To achieve the proper spacing, using `\phantom{M + {}}` - add an empty group after `+` to ensure TeX sees it as a *binary* operator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
           M +     A + T & = 12 \\
  \phantom{M + {}} A + T & = 10
\end{align*}

\[
  \begin{cases}
             M +     A + T & = 12 \\
    \phantom{M + {}} A + T & = 10
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

You are probably better off using the following `cases`:

[image]

```
\[
  \begin{cases}
             M +     A + T = 12 \\
    \phantom{M + {}} A + T = 10
  \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: Your last tip indeed looks nicer. I will probably mark your answer as accepted for providing more information.

Answer (score 6):

They do, but since you have aligned the two lines with & the space on left does not matter.

If you want the "Case" example to be aligned you have to add {} because + is a binary operator and Latex adds space between an operator and its arguments. Hence if there is no argument, as in your case, then no space is added.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\[
\begin{cases}
M+A+T & =12\\
\phantom{M+{}}A+T & =10
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Hope I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `align` makes a pair of columns, one right aligned and one left aligned, so the `\phantom` does nothing in the case of `align` or `align*`.

In order to get the correct spacing you need an empty group: `\phantom{M+{}}`, because only in this way TeX will consider `+` as a binary operation symbol.

However there's a simpler solution:

```
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}[t]
M+A+T &= 12
A+T &= 10
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
```

Full comparison:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{cases}
M+A+T = 12\\
\phantom{M+{}}A+T = 10
\end{cases}
\]

\[
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}[t]
M+A+T &= 12\\
A+T   &= 10
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      M+A+T &= 12\\
      A+T &= 10
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your vertical alignment seems to be off here. You need `\begin{aligned}[t]`, as suggested in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393535/5764).

Comment: @Werner: Your suggestion does not work.

Comment: So why does it work in the other smart?